# My dog is pulling her fur out and eating it

Tags: dogs, eating, grooming, biting

She is a 13 year old Labrador and I have I just started to notice this problem. It does not seem to be too bad, but it makes me worry about her. I am dog sitting for a family member so I cannot take her to the vet or anything if it is just something small. I can't lift her to give her a bath but is there something I can try? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Any skin issues need to be seen by a vet as a number of things can make a dog pull out their fur/overgroom.

some examples are flea allergy dermatitis, allergies, skin infection etc.

Can never guarantee 100% as to what it is without being able to see the dog in person.